# Отображение файлов с форматом .gif из базы mysql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gif

Файлы с форматом .gif сохраняются также, как и обычные статичные картинки? Обычные картинки отображаются на сайте с помощью ссылки из базы данных mysql, например: 'background: url("http://localhost:8080/files/836982cc-a40b-4037-b7e3-344f2aa9aecf")'. Но с гифками так не работает, примерно такое же реализовано на сайте https://tenor.com/, я посмотрел через консоль и там что-то похожее, как я хочу сделать.

Код для сохранения файл с помощью Spring в базу данных mysql взял с этого сайта https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload/, в интернете про гифки ничего не нашёл.

Фронт - angular 13, бэк - Spring

Comment: Браузеру все равно в каком формате картинка. gif он должен открыть точно так же как и jpg или что то другое. Но вообще желательно, что бы web-сервер при отдаче файла указал правильный content-type. А так как веб сервера определяют его по расширению (если другое не указано в конфигурации), то возникает вопрос, а какой же контент он ставит если у файла нет расширения. А вообще стоит посмотреть у себя на сайте в консоли нет ли ошибок относительно вашей картинки

Comment: где контроллер который отдает gif'ки? какой content-type он выдает?